# TeamCity: Deploying specific projects in feature branches from large repositories

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I've yet to find suitable advice on a sustainable continuous deployment workflow that fits our organizations applications. We're currently using a single, large repository to house all our source code, with multiple VS2010 *.sln files to group related products/tools. We're also using a branch strategy similar to the `develop` and `master` outlined in [this great article](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) though via mercurial not git.  The applications vary widely from public websites, internal websites, windows services, utilities, and development tools.

Even some of the comprehensive [examples I found](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html) don't really address deployment at various levels within the repository (unless I missed it).

My default build points at the `main.sln` at the root of the repository -- building all projects in the respository. This configuration is also set to build any feature branches.

The feature branches are branches of the entire repository, but I don't want to deploy *everything* to test, just the contents of that sub-solution. I aslo don't want to require branches be merged to `develop` prior to being built. How do I indicate to TeamCity (or my repository) that I only want to deploy specific projects, which could vary between feature branches?

Note: This is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163715/mercurial-workflow-with-selective-feature-deployment-and-continuous-integration), but with emphasis on multiple smaller projects that have different usages/release requirements.

Comment: can you give us more insight? is it a web project? technology? are you using git (as it seems by your first link) or SVN (second one) or Mercurial (third one)?